# Why doesn't Sass `map-get()` return an error for a non-existent key?

Tags: sass, node-sass

Why doesn't `map-get()` throw an error when the key does not exist in the supplied map?

For example:

```
$map: (
  'keyone': 'value',
  'keytwo': 'value',
  'keythree': 'value'
);

map-get($map, 'keyfour');
```

I'm aware of `map-has-key()` and I understand that might be useful on its own, but if I want to use `map-get()` smoothly, I shouldn't have to call `map-has-key()` each and every time. I'd expect the `map-get()` to throw an error, but instead it fails silently. Why is this not built into Sass?

If it matters, I'm using node-sass 3.2.0.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The behavior of `map-get()` returning `null` rather than throwing an error when a key is not found in the mapping is by design.  From the maintainer of Sass (on why `nth()` throws an error when requesting a missing element but `map-get()` does not):

> In general, it's good to throw errors as early as possible when code is doing something wrong. It's very likely than an out-of-range list access is accidental and incorrect; by contrast, a missing key in a map is much more likely to be purposeful.

via https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1721

I happen to disagree with nex3 on this (`map-get()` *should* throw an error, or at the very least throw a warning that can be suppressed).  You can get your desired behavior by writing your own custom map-get function:

```
@function map-get-strict($map, $key) {
    @if map-has-key($map, $key) {
        @return map-get($map, $key);
    } @else {
        @error "ERROR: Specified index does not exist in the mapping";
    }   
}

$map:
  ( one: 1
  , two: 2
  );

.foo {
  test1: map-get-strict($map, one); // returns the expected value of `1`
  test2: map-get-strict($map, three); // raises an error
}
```

Comment: Nice. The error doesn't show where you went wrong. Is that possible as well?

Comment: For example which filename

Comment: Just for completion, @error should provide that information already by default: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/error