# Print out sass keys from a map

Tags: function, sass

Similar to [this older answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31948731/1924257), I'd like to dump out possible values in the map that could be used.

Is there a sugared way in dart-sass to dump out just map's keys?

```
@function map-keys($map) {
  $keys: ();

  @each $key, $_ in $map {
    $keys: append($keys, $key);
  }

  @return $keys;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is in fact a built in function around map keys. Where given a sass map, `map-keys` returns a list of the keys.

```scss
map.keys($map)
map-keys($map) //=> list
```

Returns a comma-separated list of all the keys in $map.

```scss
@use "sass:map";

$font-weights: ("regular": 400, "medium": 500, "bold": 700);

@debug map.keys($font-weights); // "regular", "medium", "bold"
```

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/modules/map/#keys

Answer (score 1):

The `append` function returns a **new** list, so for each loop iteration you will need to reassign the value of `$keys`. You can use `@debug` to dump the value of your list to the console.

**SCSS:**

```scss
@function map-keys($map) {
  $keys: ();

  @each $key, $_ in $map {
    // Add key to list of keys
    $keys: append($keys, $key);
  }

  @return $keys;
}

$colors: (
  "red": #f00,
  "green": #0f0,
  "blue": #00f
);

$color-keys: map-keys($colors);

// Log color keys
@debug $color-keys;
```

**Console output:**

```
"red" "green" "blue"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing out that logic bug. But it still looks like there's no built-in sugar for this.